# Excel VBA Find & Replace Instances

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to find and replace certain words in a text string in excel. The issue I have is that the code re-replaces words that have already been replaced.  For example if I have a text string

> "The boy rode his bike up the lane and then rode his cycle back"

In my list I have

```
 A      B    
cycle  bike     
bike   cycle
```

I want to replace the word 'bike' to 'cycle' but then the other word 'cycle' later on in the sentence to 'bike'.

So I want to get from This

> "The boy rode his bike up the lane and then rode his cycle back"

to this

> "The boy rode his cycle up the lane and then rode his bike back"

When I run the code it converts both words to bike which is logical as it will find the word 'cycle first and change it to bike and then because it changed it to bike it will then replace both instanced to cycle therfore making "The boy rode his cycle up the lane and then rode his cycle back"

So basically once a word has been replaced I don't want the code to replace it again?

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()    
    Dim Rng As Range    
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range    
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"    
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection        
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)    
    Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells    
        InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value    
    Next    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks vba4all that works perfectly - you star